# Web.api MultipartFormDataStreamProvider not reading PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hello i'm trying to upload files via web.api and i have this working code:

```
var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
        ContinueWith<IHttpActionResult>(o => {

           for (int i = 0; i < provider.FileData.Count; i++) {

                    //Working Save file code

           }
      }
);
```

The problem is, if i upload and image `provider.FileData.Count` is `> 0` and the file data is present but if I upload a Pdf `provider.FileData.Count` is `== 0` and i don't receive any data...

client side the code is as follows:

```
formData_object = new FormData();

$.each($form.serializeArray(), function(i, item) {
    formData_object.append(item.name, item.value);                          
});

//and then add files
$form.find('input[type=file]').each(function(){
    var field_name = $(this).attr('name');

    var files = $(this).data('files');
    if(files && files.length > 0) {
        for(var f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
            formData_object.append(field_name, files[f]);
        }
    }
});

deferred = $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData_object
})
```

As a final note the size of the pdf is 4.87Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem and is a quite simple one due to my lack of some base knowledge of the http Runtime itself. 
The file I used for testing is larger then the maximum size (4MB) but web.api was not returning any error to point me in the correct direction.

For anyone having a similar problem:

The default file(request) limit for the ASP.NET runtime is 4MB 4096KB and can be changed in web.config at:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="XXXX" />
</system.web>
```

As a side note the limit for IIS7 is 30 000 000 bytes (28.6MB) and can be changed in web.config at:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="XXXX" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```